# mirror the full PCB in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, altium

I need to flip/mirror the full PCB along the Y axis. Is there any option to do that in Altium Designer?

I only find info about how to mirror a single component but no the full PCB

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work.

1. Make sure all layers are visible.
2. edit-select all.
3. start dragging the selection.
4. press y (or was it x, I can't remember what convention altium uses for flipping).
5. click yes to the warning.
6. drop the selection back down

You may need to fix up things like board outline afterwards.

Comment: Won't this also mirror your footprints? Thus making them unusable? Might better want to press "L" to flip them to the other side.

Comment: yes it will, he told me he wanted the whole design to be mirrored so I told him how to do that. Obviously if he has any asymetric components he would have to do something about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the items you want to mirror on the PCB (it could be a few things or it could be everything), and then press **M** and then select **Flip Selection**. This will mirror everything but keep the board position the same. It will not mirror the board.

If you want to mirror the board itself too, then you can select everything you want including the board press **M**, then **Move Selection**, then press **X**.